# Google Analytics report api v4: get data from date range between two dates accurate to hours

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I trying to get Google Analytics Report api v4 data from Java code.

I using DateRange object to define startDate and endDate.

```
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
dateRange.setStartDate(startDate);
dateRange.setEndDate(endDate);
```

But The **Start** and **End** dates for the query in the format **'YYYY-MM-DD'**

Is there a way to to additionally specify a hours?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, the day starts at midnight of the view you are querying. However you can query for the hour of the day as a dimension (ga:hour for the hour of the day, or ga:dateHour for the date with the hour) and use that to filter in your results for the timeframe you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!